# c# (vbs-15) how to fill datagrid and provide links

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

Sorry guys, but am new to c# and vbs. what am trying to do is to fill datagrid or any equivalent then i need to provide click-able buttons/links to each row.

When user click the button, the app should pass the row-id clicked to new (another) form.

```
...
            p.textquery = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 250";
            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + p.dbname() + ";Version=3;");
            m_dbConnection.Open();
            try
            {
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(p.textquery, m_dbConnection);
                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                bool rows = reader.HasRows;
                if (rows)
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        patient_id = reader["patient_id"].ToString();
// Here i need to show results to user but the user should have a button to select the row
                    }
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    p.alert("You do not have members in the system");
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                p.alert("SQL has error - (database error)");
                return;
            }
...
```

The problem is how to provide datagrid or any equivalent which has button where user can click to view the record.

Your help is highly appreciated

**EDIT**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_2(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    plugin p = new plugin();
    try {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonCell)
        {
            //I need the value of the column here member_id is only showing the rowindex and columnindex now i need the value
            p.alert(dataGridView1.Rows[e.ColumnIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            p.alert(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ToString() + " on else");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception v)
    {
        //p.alert("Header clicked ");
    }
}
```

**EDIT - ANSWER**

> dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

```
where Cells[2] is the targeted cell
```

Comment: You can just a datagridview in the form and bind data, what exactly you are asking to help with ? You are unable to bind ? Or you don't know how to put a button in datagridview?

Comment: I guess both should be a problem

Comment: can you show me this? on while() i need to show the data into grid and that grid on each row i need to have a button where patient_id should be assigned to this button and pass to another event when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and drop a datagridview from the toolbox to the window, Add All the columns in your data table to it using **properties--> columns** in that add a button column or a link column. 
Bind data to grid as below

```
DataTable dtMembers = new DataTable();
p.textquery = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 250";
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + p.dbname() + ";Version=3;");
try
{
    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(p.textquery,m_dbConnection);
    m_dbConnection.Open();
    da.Fill(dtMembers);
    m_dbConnection.Close();
    if(dtMembers.Rows.Count > 0)
        dgvMembers.DataSource = dtMembers;
    else
        p.alert("You do not have members in the system");
}
catch
{
    p.alert("SQL has error - (database error)");
    return;
}
```

Implement DataGridView cell content click

```
private void dgvMembers_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(dgvMembers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonCell)
    {
        //Write your code here
    }
}
```

See below I have text property where I wrote click  here, that's where you need to put button name
[image]

Comment: It working but few problems, first the button i added by properties--> columns has no label is just a button.

No column is firing anything dgvMembers_CellContentClick()

and on dgvMembers_CellContentClick how do i get patient_id cos thats what i need to fetch related data from database.

Comment: It has text property check, you get all the data of the row or keep id in tag property. You need register content click event in the events tab of datagridview properties

Comment: **No column is firing anything dgvMembers_CellContentClick()** means the grid isn't registered for this event

Comment: if you still unable to find join the https://meetings.webex.com/collabs/meetings/join?uuid=M4P1XGIQ844XGKUNT4CQI57A5L-4O2

Comment: Yah you are right the dgvMembers_CellContentClick() wasn't reflecting right function, now i adjust it but the event isn't providing member_id nor any cell content/text all i can see is ColumnIndex and RowIndex not the contents of the cell. p.alert(dataGridView1.Rows[e.ColumnIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ToString());. i would like this dgvMembers_CellContentClick() to reciave the content of the cell so i can use it

Comment: which function has content/value/text of the cell?

Comment: am using mobile data connected to the PC, please may i av your help is the only thing remaining.

Comment: See the answer I have added image

Comment: if you are okay to show ID in the grid bind member_id to button, so that button text will have the id otherwise add another column with id and use that to get id

Comment: Fine i saw the edit; But i hope you understand that the button is able to call its assigned event but in that event am not able to get member_id value. in the event when i put alerts am able to see the alerts but i cant get the value of member_id.

Comment: That's what the previous comment check

Comment: Hey, i got the gist dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString() thats what am asking the problem is fully solved, thanks for the hand i appreciated.